# retain active content upon browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have a website I'm working on using javascript / jquery. It acts similar to an accordion, but for the whole site.. Links are positioned on the left side of the screen and when you click on one (let's say "about me") the current content (maybe the "home" or "contact" page) slides off screen and the "about me" content slides on screen. My issue lies when refreshing the page.

If the "about me" or "contact" content is being viewed and you click refresh, it resets and shows the "home" page content. I want the current content (if different than the "home" content) to remain visible when the page is refreshed.

Any suggestions on how to complete this? I've been playing with the "hashchange" event/function and can get my URL to update, but I still need the refresh to load the current content rather than the home page content every time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Either you use a cookie or localstorage, that way it will keep even between sessions, or you just refresh with something like `example.com/page#contact` and you check for that and loads the content based on the url.

Comment: can you give some code examples?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Aunnix/pen/KNROax

here is the current code.

Comment: I will check into the localstorage..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to keep something even if the browser gets refreshed:

1- Url parameters. In this case you add the current selected menu on the url like:

```
localhost?currentMenu=about
```

No when doing this you have to have a script to check that and select the corresponding menu `onLoad`.

2- localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('currentMenu', 'about');
```

And then check it onLoad:

```
currentMenu = localStorage.setItem('testObject');
```

3- coockies

document.cookie = "currentMenu=about";

Remember all of these options require to do additional checking on load.